# Environment variables in Ubuntu Tomcat, Apache and Java

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, ubuntu, environment-variables

I have a java web app running in Windows enviroment and I want to move it to Ubuntu system.
In windows I use an environment variable to store the main path:

```
MAIN_PATH=C:\test
```

This variable is used in many configuration files and  also by application, for example:

- Apache and Tomcat configuration file
- Application logging configuration (log4j)
- Java application itself by System.getEnv(...)

**examples:**

tomcat config

```
 <Host name="localhost"  appBase="${MAIN_PATH}/webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

apache virtualhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "${MAIN_PATH}/www"
    ServerName testmain
    <Directory "${MAIN_PATH}/www">
...
```

I can not find some way to set it in ubuntu, I tried this places:

```
/etc/enviroment
/etc/profile
```

`export MAIN_PATH=/opt/test` in /etc/init.d/tomcat7.sh

All this solution didn't work or works just in one of my requirements (only in server configuration but not in application or vice versa).

Is nothing like windows global environment variable to use for all this cases?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check ubuntu/linux documentation? It's fairly simple.

Refer to: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

This worked perfectly for me.

- $ nano /etc/environment (or whatever file editor you want to use)
- add 'export MAIN_PATH=/opt/test' to the file and save
- $ source /etc/environment
- $ echo $MAIN_PATH
- Output: /opt/test

Comment: Make sure when you change these files that you restart the computer or you can run the 'source' command on the file from bash IE: $source /etc/environment

Comment: I tried and tried again... no way to export variable to all services in just one file. I could run it only adding "export var..." on init.d script of each service. Can you tell me where to put enviroment vars?

Comment: Your init.d scripts might be overriding your environment variables.

Comment: @Hal50000 this is exactly my problem... both tomcat and apache seems to have their own enviroment variables.

Comment: @proulxs seems not working with init.d services. Only with user process

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you keep the environment variables separate for each layer of your application. For example it might seem like putting everything in one place makes sense, but I don't feel it's good design to share a configuration directory for Apache and Tomcat. Both have standard locations for config files (e.g., `$CATALINA_HOME/conf`).

I wouldn't think you're using log4j on Apache so why put it in a custom directory that's shared with Apache. Put it in a conf folder inside your webapp, or in the previously mentioned top level conf directory. Maybe you'll have more than one webapp on Tomcat -- in that case it makes even more sense to have logging config files within the particular webapp directory.

It's also cleaner to have the environment variables contained within the process. They don't gum up the global environment variables. For example when you start Tomcat, the setenv.sh script runs and sets all the enviroment variables just for the java process that's running Tomcat.

Comment: If this is the only solution I will consider it, however my application has many services and every service should write logs to a particular folder, will find sources on another particular folder, so in a Windows enviroment I'm using an evniroment variable with the application folder and everything is stored here and apache, tomcat and so on will point in that folder. Please see my edited question with some configuration examples

Comment: Obviously i'm not using log4j in Apache but I need to change apache logging path to my custom path (the same as log4j).

Comment: I don't believe your gaining anything by using the environment variable in your configs. For example, you don't need to use an absolute path in Tomcat's server.xml, the appBase is relative. i.e., just "webapps". I have this on both my windows dev box and RHEL production machines. I'd keep the log4j logs and the apache logs within their respective parent directories, not in the same one.

Comment: You got a very good example, I want an absolute tomcat webapps path to ${MAIN_PATH}/webapps (see my question), this because for me it is very easy to manage logs, backup and updates if everything is stored in one folder.